# error in d3.js : t.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Hope somebody can help me out because I can't find any reference about this error.

I was working on this piece of code:

```
<script>
var outerWidth = 500;
var outerHeight = 250;
var margin = {left: 90, top:30, right:30, bottom:30};
var barPadding = 0.2;

var xColumn = "Samples";
var yColumn = "Conc";

var innerWidth = outerWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
var innerHeight = outerHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", outerWidth)
        .attr("height", outerHeight);

var g = svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," +margin.top +")");
var xAxisG = g.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + innerHeight + ")");
var yAxisG = g.append("g");

var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeBands([0, innerWidth]);
var yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([innerHeight, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale).orient("bottom");
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient("left");


function render(data){

    xScale.domain(data.map(function(d){return d[xColumn];}));
    yScale.domain(0, d3.max(data, function(d){return d[yColumn];}));

    xAxisG.call(xAxis);
    yAxisG.call(yAxis);


    var bars = g.selectAll("rect").data(data);

    bars.enter().append("rect")
        .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand());

    bars.attr("x", function(d){return xScale(d[xColumn]);})
        .attr("y", function(d){return yScale(d[yColumn]);})
        .attr("height", function(d){return innerHeight - yScale(d[yColumn]);});

    bars.exit().remove();
}

function type(d){
    d.conc = +d.conc;
    return d;
}

d3.csv("conc.csv", type, render);
</script>
```

but I must have error message below in the web console:

"TypeError: t.map is not a function

Comment: What line is showing the error?

Comment: error @ http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js:2

Comment: error is not in the line...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is on this line:

```
    yScale.domain(0, d3.max(data, function(d){return d[yColumn];}));
```

It should be

```
    yScale.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){return d[yColumn];})]);
```

Note the insertion of square brackets `[` and `]`.

The [`domain()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#continuous_domain) function takes a single argument, an array with two or more entries.  You are calling it with two numbers.